# How do I put a member's image and nick on embed? (w/ discord.py)

Tags: python, embed, discord, discord.py

I want to put the avatar and nick of the person who ran a command in the embed, something like this:

```
requested by:
(avatar) (nick)
```

but I do not know how to start....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this:

```
embed.set_thumbnail(url=message.author.avatar_url)
embed.set_footer(text='ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤRequested by: ' + message.author.name)
```

Answer (score 4):

sounds like you should read more documentation, here are a few links:

rewrite: [embed](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#embed), [send](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.send)

async: [embed](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#embed), [send_message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.send_message)

otherwise here is the code that I recommend using

```
em = discord.Embed(description='requested by:\n{0}'.format(ctx.author))
em.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.author.avatar_url)

# for rewrite (1.0.0a) do
await ctx.send(embed=em)

# if you're using async 0.16.x do
await bot.say(embed=em)
```

Answer (score 0):

Theres a pretty handy tool online that you can use to create embeds using `discord.py`.

Heres a link to it: [Discord Embed Generator](https://cog-creators.github.io/discord-embed-sandbox/).

However, I highly suggest also reading the docs, to get a better understanding of what you're coding, instead of depending on that resource.

Heres the embed [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#embed).