# How do i add the image of the user in PIL (discord.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, discord, discord.py

I want to add image of the person who ran a command, i don't seem to find out how. i want their square sized profile avatar on a picture. any help is much appreciated. EDIT: This is not related to embeds, i want to put specific size photo of a user into a PIL IMAGE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I put a member's image and nick on embed? (w/ discord.py)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48412010/how-do-i-put-a-members-image-and-nick-on-embed-w-discord-py)

Comment: It's not a duplicate @PatrickHaugh, that was image on embed and this question is image with PIL (not with embed)

Comment: @Universal Music I want the same thing, I've tried as much, i'm not quite sure that this can be done with PIL